Matrices with exactly one positive value on off diagonals otherwise 0
I encountered the set $X$ of $n\times n$ matrices, which have exactly one positive value on each off diagonal and otherwise zero. I spend quite some time trying to find some structure  and also groups acting on matrices which fix $X$. Basically, orbits of such an action should contain any two matrices which differ only by sliding one value along the off diagonal to which it belongs.
Has anyone seen something like this before?
